# Material UI Button loses Styling after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I'm using useStyles to style my login page. Everything on the page has the right style and it doesn't lose it after the refresh, apart from the button.
The button is the only thing in the page that loses the styling after the refresh.

Login.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, MemoryRouter, Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStyles } from './style/Login-styling'
import { Container, Grid, Paper, Avatar, TextField, Button, Typography, Link, Snackbar } from '@material-ui/core'
import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

function TransitionUp(props) {
  return <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;
}

function Alert(props) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props}  />;
}

export default function Login() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("Wrong credentials!");
  const history = useHistory();
  const classes = useStyles();

  async function csrf() {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/csrf',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      localStorage.setItem('csrfToken', res.data.csrfToken)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    csrf();
  }, [])

  const passwordEnter = e => {
    if (e.code == "Enter") {
      login()
    }
  }; 
  const nameEnter = e => {
    if (e.code == "Enter") {
      document.getElementsByName('password')[0].focus()
    }
  }; 

  async function login() {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/login',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.getItem('csrfToken')
      },
      data: {
        name: name,
        password: password
      },
      credentials: "include",
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      if(res.data.result == "Login successful"){
        switch(res.data.job){
          case "doctor":
            history.replace("/dashboard1")
            break;
          case "pharmacist":
            history.replace("/dashboard2")
        }
      }
      else if (res.data.result == "Invalid credentials"){
        setAlert("Wrong credentials!")
        setOpen(true);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      if (err) {
        setAlert("Invalid CSRF Token!")
        setOpen(true);
      }
    })
  }

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <Container className={classes.container} component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography variant="h3" className="title">Login</Typography>
          <div className={classes.form}>
            <TextField color="secondary" margin="normal" fullWidth variant="filled" label="Name" onKeyPress={(e) => nameEnter(e)} autoFocus={true} autoComplete="off" spellCheck="false" type="text" name="name" id="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/> 
            <TextField color="secondary" margin="normal" fullWidth variant="filled" label="Password" onKeyPress={(e) => passwordEnter(e)} type="password" name="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          </div>
        <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={login}>Login</Button>
        </div>
      </Container>
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} 
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="error">
          {alert}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Login-styling.js:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    container: {
        transform: 'translate(-50%)',
    },
    button: {
        background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        fontSize: '110%',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        height: 48,
        width: '40%',
        padding: '0 30px',
        marginTop: '5%',
        '&:hover': {
            color: 'rgba(48, 48, 48, 1)',
         },
    },
    paper: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: '60%',
    },
    form: {
        width: '80%'
    },
}));
```

App.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Dashboard1 from './components/Dashboard2'
import Dashboard2 from './components/Dashboard1'
import Admin from './components/Admin'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, MemoryRouter, Redirect, useHistory, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import "./App.css";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { colors } from '@material-ui/core';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

import 'fontsource-roboto';

export default function App(){
  const history = useHistory();
  let theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark',
      secondary: {
        main: colors.blue[200]
      }
    },
  });
  theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme)
  const location = useLocation()
  const pageTransition = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "100vh",
    },
    in: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      scale : 1
    },
    out: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "-100vh",
      scale: 1,
    }
  }

  const transitionOptions = {
    type: "spring",
    ease: "anticipate",
    duration: 0.6,
    delay: 0.5
  }
  
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} style={{position: 'relative'}}>
      <CssBaseline />
        <AnimatePresence>
          <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <motion.div 
                initial="false" 
                animate="in" 
                exit="out" 
                variants={pageTransition} 
                transition={transitionOptions}
                style={{position: 'absolute', left: '50%'}}
              >
                <Login />
              </motion.div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/dashboard1">
              <motion.div 
                initial="initial" 
                animate="in" 
                exit="out" 
                variants={pageTransition} 
                transition={transitionOptions}
                style={{position: 'absolute'}}
              >
                <Dashboard1 />
              </motion.div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/dashboard2">
            <motion.div 
                initial="initial" 
                animate="in" 
                exit="out" 
                variants={pageTransition} 
                transition={transitionOptions}
                style={{position: 'absolute'}}
              >
                <Dashboard2 />
              </motion.div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/admin">
              <motion.div initial="initial" animate="in" exit="out" variants={pageTransition}>
                <Admin />
              </motion.div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </AnimatePresence>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Before refresh:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIQMA.png

After refresh:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftBXA.png

Comment: Does your project have global style/theme configurations?

Comment: The only theme is the one you see in the code with MuiThemeProvider

Comment: @Pitter forgot to tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way JSS creates styles on-demand, the core styles for the Button component are overriding the styles you've defined with `makeStyles` simply because the components are imported *after* the custom styles. If you inspect the element in Dev Tools, you can see that the `.MuiButton-root` styles are overriding those under the generated class `.makeStyles-button-2` -- two single-class CSS selectors have the same specificity, so the one that comes last ends up winning.

To fix this, you'll just want to reorder your imports, so that `useStyles` is imported after the `Button` and the rest of your MUI components.

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-lamport-0i1zt?file=/src/components/Login.js