# Material UI Button loses style after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styling

Since no one answered to my question ([Material UI Button loses Styling after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797057/material-ui-button-loses-styling-after-page-refresh)) I'm asking again, this time including a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-resonance-8c8pz?file=/src/components/style/Login-styling.js

Steps to reproduce problem:
1-Change a value in the "Login.styling.js" for the button (just to make react update the page) and now the button is the color you set.
2-Refresh the page (the button will not follow the style anymore)

Comment: Just update your previous question with the new relevant information. Or delete it and update this question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way JSS creates styles on-demand, the core styles for the Button component are overriding the styles you've defined with `makeStyles` simply because the components are imported *after* the custom styles. If you inspect the element in Dev Tools, you can see that the `.MuiButton-root` styles are overriding those under the generated class `.makeStyles-button-2` -- two single-class CSS selectors have the same specificity, so the one that comes last ends up winning.

To fix this, you'll just want to reorder your imports, so that `useStyles` is imported after the `Button` and the rest of your MUI components.

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-lamport-0i1zt?file=/src/components/Login.js

(^ I didn't know what you were trying to accomplish with the 'disabled' button background color, so I used a Primary shade instead here for the sake of demonstration)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense but i couldn't find it. The "theme.palette.disabled" is just a color in the "dark theme" palette.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in mui and my button loses its background color. because of a layout.css file generated by mui. it has following block...

```
/*
  1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
  2. Remove default button styles.
*/
 
button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
    background-color: transparent; /* 2 */
    background-image: none; /* 2 */
}
```

I don't know why this happened I mean the page was perfect just a day before and today it is happening...